# How can I create a line chart containing the overlapping data of 2 years?

Tags: javascript, apexcharts

If I fill in my data in this format:

```
            series: [{
                name: "2020",
                data: dataForThisYear
            }, {
                name: "2019",
                data: dataForLastYear
            }],
```

with type datetime, I get 2 separate line charts side by side, as it is ordered by time of course. How can I get the two lines to overlap, to see data for both years in comparison?

The whole code:

```
var options = {
            chart: {
                type: "line",
                fontFamily: 'inherit',
                height: 40.0,
                sparkline: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                animations: {
                    enabled: false
                },
            },
            dataLabels: {
                enable: true,
                position: 'bottom'
            },
            fill: {
                opacity: 1,
            },
            stroke: {
                width: [2, 1],
                dashArray: [0, 3],
                lineCap: "round",
                curve: "smooth",
            },
            series: [{
                name: "2020",
                data: dataForThisYear
            }, {
                name: "2019",
                data: dataForLastYear
            }],
            grid: {
                strokeDashArray: 4,
            },
            xaxis: {
                labels: {
                    padding: 0
                },
                tooltip: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                type: 'datetime',
            },
            yaxis: {
                labels: {
                    padding: 4
                },
            },
          
            colors: ["#206bc4", "#a8aeb7"],
            legend: {
                show: false,
            },
        };

var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);

        chart.render();
```

Comment: As a workaround for now I set the timestamp of both data sets to the same year and used the actual year as category name

Comment: That is the correct approach

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example wherein the timestamp for the *overlaid* lines is the elapsed from start of year.

```js
// make some sample data
    
    function randomInt(max) {
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
    }    
    
    var
        results_2019 = []
    , results_2020 = []
    ;
    
    a_date_in_2019 = new Date(2019,0); limit_2019 = new Date(2020,0);
    a_date_in_2020 = new Date(2020,0); limit_2020 = new Date(2021,0);
    
    y_2019 = 10;
    y_2020 = 20;
    
    for (var index=0; a_date_in_2019 < limit_2019 && a_date_in_2020 < limit_2020 && index < 1000; index++) {
            
      if (a_date_in_2019 < limit_2019) results_2019[index] = { x: a_date_in_2019, y: y_2019 };
      if (a_date_in_2020 < limit_2020) results_2020[index] = { x: a_date_in_2020, y: y_2020 };
      
      y_2019 += randomInt(5) / 2 - 1;
      y_2020 += randomInt(5) / 2 - 1.5;
      
      // add 3 days and a random number of days
      next_date = new Date();
      next_date.setTime(a_date_in_2019.getTime() + 1000*60*60*24*(3 + randomInt(3)));
      
      a_date_in_2019 = next_date;
      
      next_date = new Date();
      next_date.setTime(a_date_in_2020.getTime() + 1000*60*60*24*(3 + randomInt(3)));
      
      a_date_in_2020 = next_date;
    }    
    
    // chart the sample data
    
    var options = {
      chart: {
        type: "line",
        fontFamily: 'inherit',
        height: 300,
        sparkline: {
          enabled: true
        },
        animations: {
          enabled: false
        },
      },
      dataLabels: {
        enable: true,
        position: 'bottom'
      },
      fill: {
        opacity: 1,
      },
      stroke: {
        width: [2, 1],
        dashArray: [0, 3],
        lineCap: "round",
        curve: "smooth",
      },
      series:
        [{
            name: "2019",
            data: results_2019
         }
        ,{
            name: "2020",
            data: results_2020
        }],
      grid: {
        strokeDashArray: 4,
      },
      xaxis: {
        lines: {
          show: false,
        },        
        labels: {
          padding: 0
        },
        tooltip: {
          enabled: false
        },
        type: 'datetime',
      },
      yaxis: {
        labels: {
          padding: 4
        },
      },

      colors: ["#206bc4", "#a8aeb7"],
      legend: {
        show: true,
      },
    };

    var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);
    
    var elapsed_2019 = [];
    var elapsed_2020 = [];

    var base_2019 = new Date(2019,0);
    var base_2020 = new Date(2020,0);

    for (const result of results_2019) { elapsed_2019.push( { x:new Date(result.x - base_2019), y:result.y }) }
    for (const result of results_2020) { elapsed_2020.push( { x:new Date(result.x - base_2020), y:result.y }) }

    let options2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(options))
    options2.series[0].data = elapsed_2019;
    options2.series[1].data = elapsed_2020;    
    
    var chart2 = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart2"), options2);

    chart.render();
    chart2.render();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts?.js"></script>
  <div id="chart"></div>
  <div id="chart2"></div>
```